# Read value from linux environment in php code

Tags: php

I had exported a value from .bashrc

```
export ENV_MY_VAR="Hello world"
```

Now If I echo that variable using `echo $ENV_MY_VAR` in terminal, it print `"Hello world"` but If I echo that variable in my php file it doesn't give result. I had also tried to execute shell command using `[shell_exec][1]`, but it also gives an empty string.

How can I get the value of that varible in my php file?

Comment: PHP has [getenv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php)

Comment: getenv also does not givning the value.

Comment: before posting that question, I had tried that already.

Comment: I think that variable is only set when you run `bash` - since it's declared in `.bashrc`. But I could be wrong on that

Comment: It may be possible, but how could I read that value in that php file?

Comment: Because I had tried lot of things but can't get that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
echo(getenv('ENV_MY_VAR');
```

make sure that you edit the .bashrc that apache2 uses. My apache2 uses the .bashrc from root.
also you can use

```
print_r(getenv());
```

to get all env vars.

also source your .bashrc

Comment: Nope!, dosn't work. In bash, it gives the result but when I run file using localhost on browser it returning empty string.

Comment: Can you try the env 'EDITOR' ?

Comment: No I had not used, because I don't know about it.

Comment: How can I use that?

Comment: @SurajSingh i edited my answer ! your apache session propably uses some other user's .bashrc maybe root